# dpkg error when using apt-get install

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 from 12.04 and every time I use `apt-get install` for any package it ends with a bunch of errors about processing some of my latex packages. Including a snippet below:

```
Sometimes, not accepting conffile updates in /etc/texmf/updmap.d
causes updmap-sys to fail.  Please check for files with extension
.dpkg-dist or .ucf-dist in this directory

dpkg: error processing package tex-common (--configure):
subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of lmodern:
lmodern depends on tex-common (>= 3); however:
Package tex-common is not configured yet.
```

Reproduced by using `sudo dpkg --configure -a` and a total list of packages with this error is included here:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
tex-common
texlive-publishers
tex-gyre
texlive-latex-extra-doc
texlive-fonts-extra-doc
texlive-lang-english
texlive-luatex
texlive-generic-recommended
texlive-pstricks-doc
texlive-fonts-recommended
latex2html
latex-xcolor
texlive-pictures
texlive-fonts-extra
texlive-pictures-doc
asymptote
texlive-bibtex-extra
texlive-latex-recommended-doc
texlive-latex-recommended
doxygen-latex
texlive-pstricks
tipa
texlive-latex-base
texlive-fonts-recommended-doc
latex-beamer
texlive-font-utils
texlive-latex-base-doc
texlive-latex-extra
texlive-extra-utils
texlive
texlive-publishers-doc
lmodern
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Edit 1: Adding the result of trying `sudo apt-get install -f`:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
32 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up tex-common (4.04) ...
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/05TeXMF.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please  remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/15Plain.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!
Ignoring /etc/texmf/texmf.d/80DVIPDFMx.cnf during generation of texmf.cnf, please remove manually!

Running mktexlsr. This may take some time... done.
Running updmap-sys. This may take some time... 
updmap-sys failed. Output has been stored in
/tmp/updmap.DJoQcW7n
```

Comment: Suppose there's some configuration problem with tex-common, maybe try to reconfigure it by
    **dpkg --configure tex-common**

Comment: After much deliberation, I decided to remove all these 32 packages manually and reinstall them. This seems to have fixed the issue. Probably needed rebuilding after the 14.04 update. Closing this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The removal of the offending packages and reinstalling them (and dependencies) fixed the issue entirely.

This is apparently a [bug](http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tex-common/+bug/1236951) as noted by user Andrea .

Answer (score 0):

if the problem occurs with apt-get it self, try to check your software repository at:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

and replace its content with appropriate repos depending on your location then do:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: I don't see why the sources.list would cause this. These were latex packages that were already installed in my pre-updated OS and I have no third party sources added.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should try to fix dependency problems before installing new packages. Try to run:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then try again to install the desider package.

Comment: These are all packages that were already installed in 12.04, and these errors appear no matter what I'm trying to install using `apt-get`. Adding more info in original post.

Comment: It's filed as a bug on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tex-common/+bug/1236951 and one user solved with the commands provided here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tex-common/+bug/1236951/comments/12

Comment: Thanks Andrea, I just saw this comment now and realized that my own solution inadvertently did the same thing. I didn't, however, remove the /etc/texmf folder since I have custom LaTex style files there and just reinstalling everything has worked just fine.